# Windows 'start /b' command problem

Tags: windows, command

I want to run the Tshark.exe in a background. Please can you tell me what is the problem in this command.

```
start /b "c:\Program Files\Wireshark\tshark.exe" -i 1 -w file1.pcap
```

This cmd is giving me this error "Windows can not find '-i'......)

Comment: how about: start /b "c:\Program Files\Wireshark\tshark.exe -i 1 -w file1.pcap"

Answer (score 11):

```
start /b "Window Title" "c:\Program Files\Wireshark\tshark.exe" -i 1 -w file1.pcap
```

`start` interprets the first string enclosed in double quotes as the title of the window it should create.

**Update**:

After @Ray Toal's comments I tried some combinations:

```
L:\>start /b "L:\tools\scjview.exe" -i
The system cannot find the file -i.

L:\>start /b "test" "L:\tools\scjview.exe" -i
L:\>
```

Comment: Are you sure about this?  According to Microsoft's documentation at http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/start.mspx?mfr=true the window title must come before the `/b`.

Comment: @ray thx, going to run some tests. ran into the same problem on friday.

Comment: @Ray seems like `start` does not care if it is before or after /b, first thing in quotes is used as a title, everything after that is filename and parameters.

Answer (score 7):

```
start /b "" "c:\Program Files\Wireshark\tshark.exe" -i 1 -w file1.pcap
```

Answer (score 0):

```
set PATH=%PATH%;c:\Program Files\Wireshark\
start /B tshark -f -i 1 -w file1.pcap
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your solution

Answer (score 0):

i counter this problem also,and i found when use "start /b" you cannot use full path
exe to run.you only can you %PATH% or copy the exe to current path.